# Creating NTP query packets with Scapy amplification

Tags: networking, scapy, ntp

I am trying to create a NTP query packet with Scapy such that I should get an amplified response, maybe even a little. For example: I tried creating a dns query with qtype as ANY and got a response larger than the request packet. I would like to achieve something of that sort. But so far, I have noticed that the request and response packets of NTP are of the same size. Is there a type of NTP query in response to which I can get a larger response?

Comment: You might want to add some code so people can see exactly how you're doing it.

Comment: I recall an NTP amplification security flaw which has since been fixed in most responsible implementations; what are you doing?

Comment: @Andrew you probably mean the monlist command. We have this project at our school and I have to show them that my program and calculate the amplification factor. It doesnt have to be very large, just enough so that it shows some amplification.

Comment: @Andrew like for example the request for an A record query would still be a bit higher in size then its query. I just have to show them that the response size in fact was a bit larger than the query packet size.